# Factorio Style Power Line in Unity

Tags: c#, linq, unity-game-engine

TLDR; How would you make power lines without infinite recursion?
I am currently working on a game where you place buildings and power lines between them to transfer power from coal factories to buildings that need power. Is there an algorithm or specific way of programming power lines so that they can transfer power between themselves and to and from other buildings. The main problem is doing this without having energy build up and exponentially increase. Considering there can be any number of power lines connected to any other amount, this is difficult.
Any tips or help?

Comment: In Factorio as power poles are built, the grid is merged / split into interconnected segments. The power grid is *not* modelled like a water pipe network. Every tick they 1) measure how much power each consumer can use (eg due to paused inserters / assemblers) 2) work out how much power can / should be produced 3) scale building efficiency based on available power.

Comment: Thanks for the input Jeremy, but I eventually found out the solution myself after weeks of pondering and failed recursive tries...

Comment: I think maybe what you are trying to ask is the "Union Find" algorithm, a pretty good description of which you can find here https://www.coursera.org/lecture/introduction-to-algorithms/dynamic-connectivity-fjxHC  by Robert Sedgewick  ( he has a good book on algorithms as well). Scroll to the bottom to get links to all the videos on union find

Answer (score 0):

```
private void GetTotalConnections(GameObject line, List<GameObject> checker) // HOLY SHIT IT WORKS HOLY SHIT IT WORKS HOLY SHIT IT WORKS
    {
        PowerLine temp = line.GetComponent<PowerLine>();
        
        if (checker.Contains(line))
        {
            if (CheckIfConnectionsContains(checker, line.GetComponent<PowerLine>()) == true)
            {
                return;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < temp.connectedLines.Count; i++)
        {
            if (checker.Contains(temp.connectedLines[i]) == false)
            {
                checker.Add(temp.connectedLines[i]);
                GetTotalConnections(temp.connectedLines[i], checker);
            }
            else // if its already in the list, skip this entry since we already checked that it still had some new connections
            {
                continue;
            }
        }
    }

    private bool CheckIfConnectionsContains(List<GameObject> list, PowerLine line)
    {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < line.connectedLines.Count; i++)
        {
            if (list.Contains(line.connectedLines[i]))
            {
                count++;
            }
        }

        if (count == line.connectedLines.Count) // if every connection is already in the list
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: connectedLines is a list of power lines currently connected to the current line. The GetTotalConnections function take in a base power line object, which is just the gameObject the script is attatched to for the first time, and list that does not change. It sets the list that does not change into one big list that gets every single power line connected to every other power line in the system.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You can edit your own question and post so you don't have to add the supporting information as a comment to your answer.